# How to deal with SIGSEGV in C++

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault, glibc

Here is a func for (i guess) transposing matrix executed, as an arg of a vector copy-constructor:

```
vector<vector<double>> tB(trans(B));
```

I have a segmention fault here:

```
vector<vector<double>>& trans(vector<vector<double>>* matrix)
{
    vector<vector<double>> result(matrix->size(), vector<double>(matrix->size(), 0.0)); <-- HERE   

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix->size(); ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix->size(); ++j) {
            result.at(i).at(j) += matrix->at(j).at(i);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Doesn't matter, even if i do this:

```
vector<vector<double>>& trans(vector<vector<double>>* matrix)
{
    vector<vector<double>> result; <-- AGAIN SIGSEGV ERROR 

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix->size(); ++i) {
        vector.push_back(vector<double>(matrix->size(), 0.0));
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix->size(); ++j) {
            result.at(i).at(j) += matrix->at(j).at(i);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: `trans` returns a reference to an object on the stack, which is deleted when `trans` returns. This is undefined behaviour. You should return a value, not a reference.

Comment: @WernerHenze you are my God! Omg, i'm so stupid, huh...

Comment: @WernerHenze write it as an answer, please. I'll mark it

Comment: Will && not help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`trans` returns a reference to an object on the stack, which is deleted when `trans` returns. This is undefined behaviour. You should return a value, not a reference. So the only change is in the function signature.

```
vector<vector<double>> trans(vector<vector<double>>* matrix)
```

BTW, if you expect matrix to never be `nullptr`, you should consider making it a reference (compare [CppCoreGuidelines](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rf-in)).